# Как изменить размер MetroMessageBox

Tags: c#, gui, metro-framework

Всем доброго дня! Собственно сабж. Вот такое окошко выскакивает: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вызываю так:

```
MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this.Parent, "Вы уверены, что хотите закрыть вкладку \x022" + name +                     
                "\x022?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
```

Как можно уменьшить его ширину (регулировать)?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroFramework/ - этот пакет используете или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ага

Comment: Можно наследовать класс от MetroMessageBox и там переопределить высоту/ ширину которая вам нужна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользовательский контрол `MetroMessageBox`:

```
using MetroFramework;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Media;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Класс `MyMessageBox`:

```
public class MyMessageBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message)
    { return Show(owner, message, "Notification", 211); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, int height, int width = 0)
    { return Show(owner, message, "Notification", height, width); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title)
    { return Show(owner, message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, 211); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title, int height, int width = 0)
    { return Show(owner, message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, height, width); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="buttons"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    { return Show(owner, message, title, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.None, 211); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="buttons"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, int height, int width = 0)
    { return Show(owner, message, title, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.None, height, width); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="buttons"></param>
    /// <param name="icon"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    { return Show(owner, message, title, buttons, icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 211); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="buttons"></param>
    /// <param name="icon"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, int height, int width = 0)
    { return Show(owner, message, title, buttons, icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, height, width); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="buttons"></param>
    /// <param name="icon"></param>
    /// <param name="defaultbutton"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultbutton)
    {
        return Show(owner, message, title, buttons, icon, defaultbutton, 211);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a metro-styles message notification into the specified owner window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="buttons"></param>
    /// <param name="icon"></param>
    /// <param name="defaultbutton"></param>
    /// <param name="height" optional=211></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, String message, String title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultbutton, int height, int width = 0)
    {
        DialogResult _result = DialogResult.None;

        if (owner != null)
        {
            Form _owner = (owner as Form == null) ? ((UserControl)owner).ParentForm : (Form)owner;

            switch (icon)
            {
                case MessageBoxIcon.Error:
                    SystemSounds.Hand.Play(); break;
                case MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation:
                    SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play(); break;
                case MessageBoxIcon.Question:
                    SystemSounds.Beep.Play(); break;
                default:
                    SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play(); break;
            }

            MetroMessageBoxControl _control = new MetroMessageBoxControl();
            _control.BackColor = _owner.BackColor;
            _control.Properties.Buttons = buttons;
            _control.Properties.DefaultButton = defaultbutton;
            _control.Properties.Icon = icon;
            _control.Properties.Message = message;
            _control.Properties.Title = title;
            _control.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            _control.ControlBox = false;
            _control.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            _control.TopMost = true;
            _control.Size = new Size(width == 0 ? _owner.Size.Width : width, height);
            _control.Location = new Point(_owner.Location.X + (_owner.Width - _control.Width) / 2, _owner.Location.Y + (_owner.Height - _control.Height) / 2);
            _control.ArrangeApperance();
            int _overlaySizes = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(_control.Size.Height * 0.28));

            _control.ShowDialog();
            _control.BringToFront();
            _control.SetDefaultButton();

            Action<MetroMessageBoxControl> _delegate = new Action<MetroMessageBoxControl>(ModalState);
            IAsyncResult _asyncresult = _delegate.BeginInvoke(_control, null, _delegate);
            bool _cancelled = false;

            try
            {
                while (!_asyncresult.IsCompleted)
                { Thread.Sleep(1); Application.DoEvents(); }
            }
            catch
            {
                _cancelled = true;

                if (!_asyncresult.IsCompleted)
                {
                    try { _asyncresult = null; }
                    catch { }
                }

                _delegate = null;
            }

            if (!_cancelled)
            {
                _result = _control.Result;
                _control.Dispose(); _control = null;
            }

        }

        return _result;
    }

    private static void ModalState(MetroMessageBoxControl control)
    {
        while (control.Visible)
        { }
    }
```

Применение:

```
MyMessageBox.Show(Owner, "Приветствую сообщество !", "Приветствие", 120, 300);
```

[image: MetroFramework MyMessageBox]

Comment: Ого, как всё не просто)